# not able to start coding in python

Tags: python

i want to code in python and i know the syntax well.. but i have got no idea how to compile and run it ..!! i mean i am from ruby , java , c , c++ background and there after saving it in a file we go to command prompt and type the command and the file name to compile and run it .
then what about python ?
why does python filename.py doesnt work ?

and how to make a file run then ?
and which python books to follow for better understanding

i am using windows os .! and i dont want to run it line by line on the idle .. i want to write the whole code and then run it from windows command prompt

Comment: How does 'python filename.py' not work? How does it fail? On which platform does it fail?

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: -1: No example of the output showing what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what operating system are you using?... you dont need to compile python code its interprated. just invoke the command line interpreter followed by the name of your .py file

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Windows, you'll need to add the path to your Python executable to the Path environment variable; on Linux, and I presume Mac, this should already be done.

Oh, and you don't compile python programs, they are interpreted at run time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are from Ruby background, you should be able to handle another interpreted language, which is what python is too.

Good starter resource:

[Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/)